# How can I override configuration.php

Tags: overrides, configuration

I would like to automatically override my Joomla configuration based on the host I am using. For example:

```
$servername = getenv("HTTP_HOST");
if($servername == "localhost") {
    JConfig::host = 'localhost';
    JConfig::user = 'root';
    JConfig::password = 'pass';
    JConfig::db = 'myproject';
}
```

what is the best way to do this? (The code above does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not the good idea to modify the config file but here is one way to do this

```
$servername = getenv("HTTP_HOST");
if($servername == "localhost") {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'pass';
    $db = 'myproject';
}

//now use it in the config file like this 
define('DB', $db);
define('DBHOST', $dbhost);
define('USR', $usr);
define('PWD', $pwd);

class JConfig {

    public function __construct(){
            $this->host = DBHOST;
            $this->user = USR;
            $this->password = PWD;
            $this->db = DB;
    }
    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $password;
    public $db;
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot - I have simplified it a bit - I put my server condition directly into the constructor, so I don't need variables and defines.